# python3 -O file.py didn't create file.pyo

Tags: python, python-3.x, bytecode, pyo

I wrote a simple script `test.py`, containing:

```
print('hello')
```

and then use `python -O test.py` to run it. I expected this to create a `test.pyo` file but it did not.

My version is Python 3.5.2. Why was no cache file created?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python only creates bytecode cache files for *imported modules*. The main script (here `test.py`) is not cached. It doesn't matter what optimisation level is applied.

*Import* `test`:

```
$ python -O -c 'import test'
hello
$ ls __pycache__
test.cpython-35.opt-1.pyc
```

Note that the cache file was created in a *separate directory*, named `__pycache__`, and that the filename is based not only on the module name, but also on the Python version and the optimisation level; use `-OO` to get `.opt-2`. As of Python 3.5, the `.pyo` filename extension is no longer used, see [PEP 488 -- *Elimination of PYO files*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0488/), and see [PEP 3147 -- *PYC Repository Directories*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/) as to why a separate directory is used.

If you want to pre-compile your modules, use the [`python3 -m compileall` tool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/compileall.html).